# Problems with URL of controller actions

Tags: php, yii2

I am having difficulties with URL routing in Yii2.

When I call the following url from the browser (Firefox) as follows I get a 404 error:

```
web/index.php?r=iol-calculation%2Findexbyname%26date%3D"2015-02-02"
```

But when I change to the literals as follows, it works fine:

```
web/index.php?r=iol-calculation/indexbyname&date="2015-02-02"
```

Can anyone tell me why the call from the browser fails?

Comment: Please, show you error, `urlManager` config and controller

Comment: urlManager:       'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => false,  // set this to false until you reset the httpd.conf file for pretty URLs
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],

Comment: Solved it with using use yii\helpers\Url; url::to() - Thanks